# How do I display the index of a list element in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, position

I've got the following code:

```
hey = ["lol", "hey", "water", "pepsi", "jam"]

for item in hey:
    print(item)
```

Do I display the position in the list before the item, like the following?

```
1 lol
2 hey
3 water
4 pepsi
5 jam
```

<sub>This is for a homework assignment.</sub>

Comment: Note all the "+1"s in the answers. Python starts with an index of 0, not 1. So the proper positions are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best method to solve this problem is to enumerate the list, which will give you a tuple that contains the index and the item. Using `enumerate`, that would be done as follows.

In [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3):

```
for (i, item) in enumerate(hey, start=1):
    print(i, item)
```

Or in [Python 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_2):

```
for (i, item) in enumerate(hey, start=1):
    print i, item
```

If you need to know what Python version you are using, type `python --version` in your command line.

Comment: no need for space between them  `,` also adds a space

Comment: @Arman Thanks! Corrected it.

Comment: @LeejaySchmidt im in high school , so can you explain to me what does --hey.index(item)+1,item-- mean  , i dont uderstand why did you put --index(item)+1 and why did you put --,item at the end

Comment: Arrays in Python start indexing at `0`, so you have to have `index(item)+1` to start printing the indexes at `1` instead of `0` (otherwise you would get `0 lol` and `1 hey`, etc.). The `,item` concatenates the `string` representation of the item with what is preceding the comma, otherwise it would just print out the index.

Comment: @LeejaySchmidt Thanks , really appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Have fun learning!

Comment: Won't work correctly if there are repeated items. And wow, it's kind of inefficient to do a lookup in every iteration.

Comment: @TomZych Good points, and they're well taken. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: The first two pieces of code are really bad advice and should be deleted.  Using `enumerate` is the way to go.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I agree. I have removed the methods that involved a traversal of the list first, and now only recommend enumerating the list.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `start` parameter of the `enumerate` buit-in method:

```
>>> hey = ["lol", "hey","water","pepsi","jam"]
>>> 
>>> for i, item in enumerate(hey, start=1):
    print(i,item)


1 lol
2 hey
3 water
4 pepsi
5 jam
```

Comment: why did you put the -V in i,v

Comment: @dragyitutorial what -V ?...i is the index, v is the item at that index...

Comment: @dragyitutorial, I've replaced v with item, does it make sense now?

Comment: ok , learned something , but can the -V be another random letter

Comment: and why do i need to put the item at the index (Sorry for stupid question)

Comment: @dragyitutorial .. I suggest you take a read the doc from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

```
hey = ["lol","hey","water","pepsi","jam"]

for (num,item) in enumerate(hey):
    print(num+1,item)
```