# Select file in a directory by index/number

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to read a file from a list. Specifically, I would need to look for a file stored in a specific directory. Since it may happen to not remember all the files stored there or just the right name, I would need to list theirs. To do this step, I found this useful post:

[How do I display the the index of a list element in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753872/how-do-i-display-the-the-index-of-a-list-element-in-python)

Now I have a list like the following:

```
file=[]

for f in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    file.append(f)


for (num,item) in enumerate(file):
    print(num+1,item)        # updated after Thierry's comment
```

Output:

```
1 file 1.txt
2 file_2.txt
3 file_3.txt
...
```

I would like to read the file using

```
query=input("Please add your selection: ") # just the number
if int(query) in enumerate(datasets):
    dataset=pd.read_csv('path_name'+1) # I would need to add the path to the file and, by the number, the filename 
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
```

it gives me the error: TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable.

How could I do this?

Comment: The beginning of the answer you used is really bad advice. Don't use `index` that way. See the end of the answer or the other ones using `enumerate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Thierry said in the comments, I would probably avoid that method and try something like this:

```
files = [f for f in glob.glob("*.txt")]

for fi, f in enumerate(files):
    print(fi, f)

query = input("Please add your selection: ") # just the number
df = pd.read_csv(files[int(query)])
```

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions for side effects:  `[print()... for...]` uselessly creates a list of `None`s (the return values of the print functions). Use comprehensions when the goal is to create a list, write normal loops otherwise. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a slightly different approach using dictionaries.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# iterate over a list of files in directory
filelist = [files for files in os.listdir("<path to directory>")]

# convert the files list to a dictionary
filelist_dict = { ind: name for (ind,name) in enumerate(filelist) }

# ask for user input
userinput = int(input("Enter a number :"))

# open the file based on the key input by user
with open(filelist_dict[userinput]) as file:
       df = pd.read_csv(file)  # read the csv file into a pandas dataframe
       print(df)               # print the dataframe
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: after selecting the query, how could I go back to the text? For example, if I select 4 and I want to see its corresponding text, would it be possible as well in the steps you showed me? I can open a new question if you prefer

Comment: @still_learning if you want to open a file and read its content, then in the last section of the snip, instead of file.read(); you could read the csv file like pandas.read_csv("filename"). I have updated the code. check if this helps

Comment: first of all thank you so much for answering me. I have tried your code, but I think I am doing something wrong because it is giving me an error. However, the main problem is that I cannot see the list of files, but only write the number to select. What I would like to understand if it would be possible, after selecting the number, trying to get back the filename, in order to create a new file just using 'file' (like stackoverflow.txt rather than 1). I am opening a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61415508/create-a-new-file-name-after-decoding-an-input-value