# Create a new file name after decoding an input value

Tags: python, pandas

In this post I have asked how to select files in a directory by using a number as index. Now I would like to save this file in an automatic way, without adding manually the name. For example:

I have the following list, generated by the code (as suggested by Eric M):

```
files = [f for f in glob.glob("*.txt")]

for fi, f in enumerate(files):
    print(fi, f)

query = input("Please add your selection: ") # just the number
df = pd.read_csv(files[int(query)])
```

Output:

```
1     text1.txt
2     text2.txt
3     text3.txt
...
```

After some changes in the dataframe, I would like to save the new table into a new file, e.g.

```
text1_test.txt
```

or

```
text2_test.txt
```

However, to do this I would need to get back information about the number that I selected in the code above, i.e. by `query`.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one solution there can be many. When you read the dataframe, save the name of the file as the name of the index and later you can use this variable in case `query` no longer is available:

```
df = pd.read_csv(files[int(query)])
df.index.name = files[int(query)]

# Do other stuff

csv_name = df.index.name.split('.')[0] + '_test.txt'
df.to_csv(csv_name)
```